# kex: command not found on WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, kali-linux, wsl2

I have installed kali linux WSL distribution. I had also installed `kali-win-kex`, as mentioned in the official documentation. However when I try to run `kex` on the Kali terminal, it exits with the following message:

```shell
-bash: 'kex': command not found
```

I used `grep` on `/var/log/dpkg.log` to find any mention of the string `kali-win-kex`, but it found no match.

**BEFORE CLOSING THIS AS A DUPLICATE** I have searched through this stackexchange and pretty much every other site for this error, and I found no solution. I have found a lot of questions here related to `kex`, however all of them are related to some kind of mode in the program. There was no problem for anyone actually starting `kex` up.

**Side note not related to this question** : Why isn't there a kex tag?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same message too and I recoverd this error as following step.

1. When first installing kali-win-kex, I had a few errors "404 not found".
   command "apt-get update --fix-missing".
   I still had a error.
2. command "apt update".
   There are a few list of updatable. command "apt list --updatable".
3. command "apt upgrade".
   I still had a error. I exited prompt and restart kali linux.
4. command "apt update" again.
   There was no updatable list.
5. command "apt install -y kali-win-kex" again.
   There was no error.
6. command "kex --win -s".
   Entered password and reply password.
   After a few seconds, The Kali Linux password small window will appear.
   Entered password and done, you will show Kali linux desktop !!

Thanks